Display different stages based on selected branch in azure devops pipeline
I have 3 environments A, b & C
When running pipeline for main branch I want to deploy to A & B and for any other branch pipeline should deploy only to C
To achieve this, I am using $(Build.SourceBranchName) variable and have written condition based on that.
ex:
if(Build.sourceBranchName == main ){
deploy to A&B
}
else
{
deploy to C
}


This implementation works fine and I am able to achieve desired output.
But in the UI after choosing branch, if I click on stages to run, it always displayed stage deploy to C.

I did debug and found that Build.SourceBranchName is empty during that time and is available when I click the run button.
How can I fix this?
Is there any other way to get branch name and display stages as per seleted branch?

Hi @Jaanu, this is the expected behavior. Check my answer below for the cause and workaround.

This is the expected behavior. Predefined variable Build.SourceBranchName isn't available until compile time. Before you click the Run button, the value of the variable Build.SourceBranchName is empty. See the example below for better understanding.
stages:
  - stage: stage0
    displayName: stage0 - This stages run without condition
    jobs:
    - job: job0
      steps:
      - script: echo ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] }}
 
  - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
    - stage: stage1
      displayName: stage1 - Run only if source branch name is ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] }}
      jobs:
      - job: job1
        steps:
        - script: echo ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] }}
 
  - ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
    - stage: stage2
      displayName: stage2 - Run only if source branch name is NOT ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] }}
      jobs:
      - job: job2
        steps:
        - script: echo ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranchName'] }}



Stage0 is visible: There isn't any condition in this stage.
Stage1 is invisible: The value of variable Build.SourceBranchName is empty and does not satisfy eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main'), so it is not visible before compilation.
Stage2 is visible: It satisfies ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main'). You can also see the value of Build.SourceBranchName is empty from its display name.

If you trigger the pipeline from main branch, you can see stage1 is triggered.

There is no way to display stages as per your selected branch, but you can display all stages and select the stages if you want using condition.
stages:
- stage: A
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main')
  jobs:
  - job: JobA
    steps:
      - script: echo "This is stageA"

- stage: B
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main')
  jobs:
  - job: JobB
    steps:
      - script: echo "This is stageB"

- stage: C
  condition: ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main')
  jobs:
  - job: JobC
    steps:
      - script: echo "This is stageC"


StageC will be skipped when the pipeline is triggered from main branch.


Hi @ZiyangLiu-MSFT, yes this is the exact behaviour. The variable is not available at compile. Since we are selecting branch from the dropdown, template can be reloaded by passing the branch name. I am wondering why is it not implemented that way. Hopefully they fix the issue soon.

According to the Predefined variables documentation, variable Build.SourceBranchName is available in templates, i.e. at compile time.
This means we can use template expressions such as ${{ if ... }} and ${{ else }} to generate stages depending on the value of that variable.
Example:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - name: sourceBranch
    value: $(Build.SourceBranchName)

stages:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['sourceBranch'], 'main') }}:
    - stage: DeployA
      displayName: 'Deploy to A Stage'
      dependsOn: []
      jobs:
      - deployment: DeployAJob
        displayName: 'Deploy to A'
        environment: 'A'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - script: echo 'Deploying to A...'
    - stage: DeployB
      displayName: 'Deploy to B Stage'
      dependsOn: DeployA
      jobs:
      - deployment: DeployBJob
        displayName: 'Deploy to B'
        environment: 'B'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - script: echo 'Deploying to B...'
  - ${{ else }}:
    - stage: DeployC
      displayName: 'Deploy to C Stage'
      dependsOn: []
      jobs:
      - deployment: DeployCJob
        displayName: 'Deploy to C'
        environment: 'C'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - script: echo 'Deploying to C...'

Running from main branch:

Running from other branches:


Thank you for the update. I am able to achieve this. Issue is with the ui that shows stages to run(not displaying respective stages), before we run the pipeline. I have updated picture for your reference.

@Jaanu from your screenshot it seems there is an error that needs to be fixed: This option is unavailable while parameters are invalid.

When I click on Stages to run everything works fine here: Selecting main branch shows me stages A and B; when another branch is selected it shows me stage C.

@Jaanu impossible to tell where the problem is without seeing your pipeline code.
